# getElementById doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```html
<form id="form1">
    Title: <input type="text" id="title1" size="25"/><br/><br/><br/>
    Description <input type="text" id="desc1" size="55"/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="doit();"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doit(){
    var title = document.getElementById("title1").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("desc1").value;

    document.write("<h3>Title: " + title + "</h3>");
    document.write("<h3>Description: " + description + "</h3>");
}
</script>
```

I need help with `getElementById`. My script takes the values the user typed in textboxes and when the user clicks submit the values are written to the page using `document.write`, however the code doesn't work as it expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
    document.write("Do it function");
    var title = document.getElementById("title1").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("desc1").value;

    document.write("<h3>Title: " + title + "</h3>");
    document.write("<h3>Description: " + description + "</h3>");
}
</script>
```

The execution doesn't even reach the first line of the function. In the button I have:

```
<input type="submit value="submit" onclick="doit();"/>
```

Comment: Your markup is missing a double quote. It should be `<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="doit();"/>`

Comment: attached is code snipped and it works here but it doesn't work on my browsers!! (IE, chrome neither firefox)

Comment: Why ?? is security related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change your html like this

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="doit();"/>
```

Comment: Don't just show the correction, say **what** you changed (and why).

Comment: The double quotes is missing in submit, so, change type="submit"

Comment: thanks but the double qoutes missed during the text formatting here at stackover flow, it is there in my source code

Answer (score 3):

If:

```
<input type="submit value="submit" onclick="doit();"/>
```

is indeed what you have, you're missing a quote (as should be evident by the syntax coloring, reason enough to make sure you use an editor that provides such coloring).

It should instead be:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="doit();"/>
```

You should also be aware that `document.write()`, if the document has already been closed, will automatically open *and clear* the document, so your first `write` may make the controls with those IDs disappear, depending on the structure of your HTML.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, the double quotes missed during the formatting of the source code and it does exist in my markup